# SWReveal slide "over" + dim front view

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Is it possible to customize SWReveal to slide over the front view instead of pushing it while also dimming it?

I tried `revealViewController().presentFrontViewHierarchically = true` but it resized one of the views and this isn't what I need.